# PHP nesting DOMDocument tags

Tags: php, domdocument

DomDocument xml question:

want xml to look like this

```
   <itunes:category text="Main Category">
       <itunes:category text="Sub category"/>
    </itunes:category>
```

but instead it looks like this

```
<itunes:category>text="Main Category"</itunes:category>
<itunes:category>text="Sub Category"</itunes:category>
```

here is the php:

```
$chan3 = $chan->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:category','text="Main Category"'));
$chan3 = $chan->appendChild($xml->createElement('itunes:category', 'text="Sub Category"'));
```

Having trouble nesting these xml tags properly. Don't want itunes:category to close the tag on the sub-category. Do I use something other than createElement?

Answer (score 0):

here the code

```
$xml= new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$chan = $xml->createElement('itunes:category');
$chan = $xml->appendChild($chan);
$chan->setAttribute('text','Main Category');
$chan->nodeValue = '<itunes:category text="Sub category"/>';
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

The result is ;

```
<itunes:category text="Main Category">
       <itunes:category text="Sub category"/>
    </itunes:category>
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: This looks great, but can you tell me why the "<" is parsing as &lt; on xml file instead of <? ... 6th line of your code?